# How to extract and delete text between two titles: Chorus and Verse Using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this sample string in the variable test_string. I want to delete chorus text. It is situated in this format: *[chorus etc..] chorus_text [verse etc..]*. I tried some regex patterns in python but nothing. Any idea? The pattern I am providing doesn't give me what i need. The chorus_text includes punctuation and characters.

```
test_string = """Cordae,RNP,2019.0,"RNP Lyrics[Chorus: Anderson .Paak] text text text text text text te'all tean' tean' text text text [Verse 1: YBN Cordae]."""

pattern = re.compile(r"[^\[chorus\]$][^\[verse\]]")
subbed_chorus_before_verse = pattern.findall(test_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\[Chorus:[^][]*][^[]*', '', test_string)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfEwwz/1).

*Details*:

- `\[Chorus:`  - a `[Chorus:` string
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `[^[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`.

Answer (score 2):

```
test_string = """Cordae,RNP,2019.0,"RNP Lyrics[Chorus: Anderson .Paak] text text text text text text te'all tean' tean' text text text [Verse 1: YBN Cordae]."""

re.sub('(?<=\])(.*)(?=\[)','',test_string)

# (?<=\]) : positive lookbehind for ]
# (?=\[ : positive look ahead for [
```

```
'Cordae,RNP,2019.0,"RNP Lyrics[Chorus: Anderson .Paak][Verse 1: YBN Cordae].'
```